# Upload file on SSL Page

Tags: c#, ssl, file-upload

I have an html input control () on an aspx page that is secured via SSL.  Just as a sanity check I want to make sure that the upload of the file on this page is also encrypted along with the rest of the page when the postback occurs and the request is sent to the server.

Comment: Just to be clear the page is using SSL and using Request.IsSecureConnection will return true.  I want to make sure that the secure connection will also protect any file uploads that may happen on that page.

Comment: If it returns true than the entire request (including POST data) is over SSL.  Simple as that.  I think you are worrying a little too much about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to do this if your server is configured properly.  But in your Page_Load...

```
If Not Request.IsSecureConnection
    'Whatever
End If
```

Comment: if (!Request.IsSecureConnection) { }